# How can I transform an array of lists into an array of items without affecting the order?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[list([130365]) list([80476]) list([999078, 999078]) list([86833, 86833])
 list([63767, 63767]) list([63777, 63777]) list([830166, 830166])]

>>> type(results)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And I want to transform it into an array containing just the items:

```
[130365 80476 999078 86833 86833 63767 63767 63777 63777 830166 830166]
```

Everything I've tried so far didn't work, how can I do this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) solve your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have a nested NumPy array. I've reproduced your problem.

```
import numpy as np
results = np.array([[130365], [80476], [999078, 999078], [86833, 86833] , [63767, 63767], [63777, 63777], [830166, 830166]])
```

[image]

For this problem, you can use NumPy's [concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
results_flat = np.concatenate(results)
```

[image]

**Notes:** 
1. To make sure that the array is one-dimensional (i.e., "flattened"), you can use this:

```
results_flat = np.concatenate(results).ravel()
```

In your case, this and the method above yield the same results.

[image]

2. If you want a list:

```
results_flat = np.concatenate(results).tolist()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [`from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) function:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

results = np.array([list([130365]), list([80476]), list([999078, 999078]),
                    list([86833, 86833]), list([63767, 63767]),
                    list([63777, 63777]), list([830166, 830166])])

flat_results = np.array(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(results)))
```